# Signing a X509Certificate with another Self Signed x509Certificate [acting as CA]

Tags: java, security, certificate, x509certificate, digital-certificate

I have created a self-signed certificate and encoded it successfully. But I want to sign this certificate with another self signed certificate, which will act as a Certification Authority.

The code is below:

```
X509Certificate caCert;
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
keyStore.load(null, null);
CertAndKeyGen keypair = new CertAndKeyGen("RSA", "SHA1WithRSA", null);
X500Name x500Name = new X500Name(commonName, organizationalUnit, organization, city, state, country);
keypair.generate(keysize);
PrivateKey privKey = keypair.getPrivateKey();

X509Certificate[] chain = new X509Certificate[1];

chain[0] = keypair.getSelfCertificate(x500Name, new Date(), (long) validity * 24 * 60 * 60);
keypair.getCertRequest(x500Name);

keyStore.setKeyEntry(alias, privKey, keyPass, chain);

keyStore.store(new FileOutputStream("test.keystore"), keyPass);
caCert = (X509Certificate) keyStore.getCertificate(alias);
File crtFile = new File("saif.der");
writeCertificate(new FileOutputStream(crtFile), caCert);
```

Comment: Do you want to make cross certification? or do you want to sign a self signed certificate with another self signed certificate?

Comment: @SaqibRezwan I want to sign a self signed certificate with anothre self signed certificate.

Comment: How it is possible? check the asn1sturectureof X509Certificate. Only one signature is allowed. You cannot have two signature in one certificate.

Comment: @SaqibRezwan Sorry let me clear my point, I have created one self signed certificate as mentioned in question [Issued By and Issued to are same]. Now I want to use it as Certification Authority that will issue a certificate to another user. I want to do it using Java code.

Comment: Ok, then, I misunderstood. Create the user certificate using X509V3CertificateGenerator class of bouncycastle. Then finally use the X509V3CertificateGenerator.generateX509Certificate(privateKey) method to generate the X509Certificate. Here the privateKey will be the self signed certificate's private key from PKCS12. Save the user certificate in PKCS12 format.

Comment: Yeah I got it. Thanks a lot for your concern. Plus This link proved to me of great help. 

https://code.google.com/p/openconcerto/source/browse/trunk/Modules/Module+EBICS/src/org/openconcerto/modules/finance/payment/ebics/crypto/X509CertificateGenerator.java

Comment: Ok, great to hear. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the user certificate using X509V3CertificateGenerator class of bouncycastle. Then finally use the X509V3CertificateGenerator.generateX509Certificate(privateKey) method to generate the X509Certificate. Here the privateKey will be the self signed certificate's private key from PKCS12. Save the user certificate in PKCS12 format.

Comment: And for its implementation in java code. please follow this link 

https://code.google.com/p/openconcerto/source/browse/trunk/Modules/Module+EBICS/src/org/openconcerto/modules/finance/payment/ebics/crypto/X509CertificateGenerator.java